# Update WordPress Theme, But Dont Change Some File

Tags: php, wordpress

i have one question

i am a beginner in wordpress theme develop, when latest version theme is available then user can update theme directly from dashboard

Updating the theme is replacing all the files with the latest version, my question is how to keep 1 or 2 theme files unchanged when the theme updates.

As we all know, wordpress updates do not replace the wp-config.php file, does something like this also do on theme updates? how is the method?

Comment: You want to look into child themes.

Answer (score 3):

You should migrate to using a wordpress child theme. This approach will bring [many benefits](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) including not loosing all your theme customisations when you update the theme. The use of a child theme is the solution to your question.

> If you modify a theme directly and it is updated, then your
>   modifications may be lost. By using a child theme you will ensure that
>   your modifications are preserved.